# What's the easiest way to create a case class objects from an Array of Tuple2?

Tags: arrays, scala, tuples, case-class

I have two arrays that I like to combine and create an `Array[Item]`. `Item` is a case class. Here is an example:

```
case class Item(a: String, b: Int)

val itemStrings = Array("a_string", "another_string", "yet_another_string")

val itemInts = Array(1, 2, 3)

val zipped = itemStrings zip itemInts
```

Currently I use the following solution to solve it but **I wonder if there are other possibilities** to this...

```
val itemArray = zipped map { case (a, b) => Item(a, b) }
```

Gives what I want:

```
itemArray: Array[Item] = Array(Item(a_string, 1), Item(another_string, 2), Item(yet_another_string, 3))
```

I also tried this but it doesn't work for a sequence of elements:

```
(Item.apply _).tupled(zipped:_*)

Item.tupled(zipped:_*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `map` over the Array with `Item.tupled`:

```
zipped.map(Item.tupled)
```

---

```
scala> zipped.map(Item.tupled)
res3: Array[Item] = Array(Item(a_string,1), Item(another_string,2), Item(yet_another_string,3))
```